# Heap-buffer-overflow when printf the content in 3d pointer array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

In the below code, if I add the last `printf` line, I get a heap-buffer-overflow error. Why does this happen? And how can I print the stuff saved in `a2`?

```
char ***a2 = (char***)malloc(10 * sizeof(char**));
char **a1 = (char**)malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
a1[0] = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
memset(a1[0], '#', 10);
a1[1] = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
memset(a1[1], '=', 10);
a2[0] = a1;
printf("%s", a2[0][0]);  <---- error
```

Answer (score 3):

You never zero-terminate the array of char so you can't use it as a string in a `printf`.

Instead of:

```
memset(a1[0], '#', 10);
```

Try:

```
memset(a1[0], '#', 9);  // Only memset the first 9 out of the 10 chars
a1[0][9] = '\0';        // Set the 10th char to be a string zero termination
```

Comment: Slightly more efficient (if a little more complicated) than using `calloc`, as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The strings you allocate for `a1[0]` and `a1[1]` (each of which has space for 10 characters) are then being filled with 10 copies of either `'#'` or `'='` ... which means that neither has an explicitly-set (and *required*) `nul` terminator. Thus, the `printf` call causes **undefined behaviour**.

To fix this, you can use the `calloc` function to *explicitly* initialize the memory to zero, then only set *one less* than the buffer size copies of the character required (either by reducing this to `9` or increasing the allocation to `11`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char*** a2 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char**));
    char** a1 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));

    a1[0] = calloc(10, sizeof(char)); // Sets all characters in buffer to 'nul'
    memset(a1[0], '#', 9);            // This leaves the last ('nul') intact!

    a1[1] = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    memset(a1[1], '=', 9);

    a2[0] = a1;
    printf("%s", a2[0][0]);

    // Don't forget to free the memory you have allocated ...
    free(a1[0]);
    free(a1[1]);
    free(a1);
    free(a2);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, you might like to read: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073)